# Splitting my bibliography into two parts with natbib

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, citing, natbib

I am currently finishing my thesis and my professor has asked me to split my bibliography into two sections, namely scientific sources and online/news sources. I have multiple .bib files, just because that made writing and citing easier and more clear for me. All sources are correctly labelled with either @article or @misc and look like this:

```
@article{laucuka_communicative_2018,
   title = {Communicative {Functions} of {Hashtags}},
   volume = {15},
   doi = {10.2478/jec-2018-0006},
   journal = {Economics and Culture},
   author = {Laucuka, Aleksandra},
   month = jun,
   year = {2018},
   pages = {56--62},
```

The final result should look something like this (I do not want actual bullet points, just did not find another way to display the sources below each other here):

**Bibliography**

*=== Scientific Sources ===*

- Source 1
- Source 2
- ...

*=== Online/News Sources ===*

- Source 1
- Source 2
- ...

My "setup" currently looks sth like this:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{MyReferences, References_EventDescription, References_DyadsRethoricalPart, References_ResearchMethod, References_TwitterDataSource, References_EmotionalExpressionCrisis, References_DiscussionLimitations}
```

Mind you, I have all other important parts in there as well like start and end document, this is just everything I have in regards to bibliography. Also, within the multiple .bib files I have, the articles and online sources are mixed, so there might be multiple articles and online sources within one .bib file, rather than one file just containing one type of source. If it is necessary to sort them, I could do that.

Not sure if what I am trying to do is achievable with natbib? Preferably, I would not like to switch since this will probably mess up my formatting and I'll have to go over citations again which will take a ton of time, but if there is no other way I am glad to switch to other citation packages of course.

Comment: Sounds like `multibib` should be able to do what you need …

Answer (score 1):

With `biblatex` you could simply do `\printbibliography[type=article]` to get all cited articles. With `multibib` you would have to adapt the citations and use e.g. `\citeonline` for the online resources. And with `bibtopic` you would have to reorder the bib-files.

Imho it would be worth to try to replace (in a test copy) natbib in the preamble by

```
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,natbib]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{MyReferences.bib}
\addbibresource{References_EventDescription}
 % more bib ressources
```

and the bibliography commands in the document by

```
\printbibliography[type=article]
\printbibliography[type=misc]
```

Then adapt your editor so that is uses `biber` instead of `bibtex` (or call `biber` on the command line) [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations) and look if something explodes.